# Is it possible to pass input of any kind to a method and determine what type of input is given?

Tags: java, variables, declaration

Is it possible to send any type of input to a method and find the type when doing operation on the type passed?

```
like

public methodName(int value){....}
```

instead of this

```
public methodName(anyType anValue){....}
```

I am using java 8.

Comment: Are you referring to overloaded methods?  In this case, you would implicitly know the types of the input parameters by virtue of whichever method ended up being invoked.

Comment: you can set parameter as Object and see type of interger or string or any other.

Comment: This is very vague. What are you trying to accomplish? The answer might be to overload methods, to use generics, to use reflection, or something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "best" you can do is pass in an `Object`. You can then inspect it to find out what it is (unless it is `null`, then you don't know what it was supposed to have been, if that would have mattered).

```
if (theObject instanceof String){
   // do something
} else if (theObject instanceof Number){
   // do something
}
```

But this defeats the purpose of a strongly typed language a bit and is rarely appropriate.

You are also losing any generic type information (as that is erased at runtime and only available at compile time).

As an alternative, consider providing multiple overloads of the method with different parameter types.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can sort of do that with Generic programming. Look [here](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c10/index.html) for more info on how to use generic programming with Java.

Comment: This answer is not correct.  With few exceptions, the type of a formal generic parameter in all versions of Java, up to version 8, is known only at compile time.  During compilation to byte code, generic type information is erased, making it very difficult for run-time code to determine what the formal type of a parameter was to have been.

Answer (score 1):

You  could use a generic method, something like

```
public static <T> void exampleMethod(T obj) {
    System.out.printf("%s %s%n", obj.getClass().getName(), obj);
}
```

Then you can pass any `Object` type to `exampleMethod` (or *primitive* with auto-boxing). As an example,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    exampleMethod("Hello");
    exampleMethod(123);
    exampleMethod(123.123f);
}
```

which outputs

```
java.lang.String Hello
java.lang.Integer 123
java.lang.Float 123.123
```

Comment: Without the `T` being referred to anywhere or being constrained, does this have an advantage over using `Object obj`?

Comment: @Thilo: the compiler guarantees type safety for generic types.  `Object obj` can contain any type and can therefore be not type safe.

Comment: @scottb: What does the compiler guarantee for an unconstrained `T` that is not referred to anywhere else?

Comment: `T` is not unconstrained, as far as the compiler is concerned.  `T` can only be `T` and nothing else (that's why it's type safe) whereas `Object` can contain any type, even those that would cause `ClassCastExceptions`.

Comment: @scottb: What do you mean `T` can only be `T` in `public static <T> void exampleMethod(T obj)`? How can this not be called with any type?

Answer (score 1):

Can leverage instanceof

```
public void methodName(Object value){
        if(value instanceof Integer){

        }else if(value instanceof String){

        }

}
```